# How to fix Error lazy loading React Components

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm getting a strange error and not seeing much online. A

```
[INFO] Module parse failed: Unexpected token (22:4)
[INFO] File was processed with these loaders:
[INFO]  * ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js
[INFO] You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
[INFO] | 
[INFO] |   return (
[INFO] >     <Fragment>
[INFO] |       {/* Components */}
[INFO] |       <Suspense fallback={
[INFO]
```

Comment: Appears to be related to .tsx and .js interoperability. My goal is to convert to .tsx anyway...so whatever the solution to interoperate is, I don't need it. Still curious though